# A design for adding resources to a project

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have classes **Project**,**Resource** and **File**.
where

A **Project** contains LIST of **Resources**.
Each **Resource** contains LIST of of **Files** of particular type.

This is mapped to an XML :

```
<Project>
<Resource id=1>
<File id="1" path="" type="A" />
<File id="2" path="" type="B" />
<File id="3" path="" type="B" />
<File id="4" path="" type="B" />
</Resource>
<Resource id=2>
<File id="1" path="" type="A" />
<File id="2" path="" type="B" />
<File id="3" path="" type="B" />
<File id="4" path="" type="B" />
</Resource>    
</Project>
```

So basically every resource has to have at-most one file of type "A" and any number of files of type "B" . The file type is selected by user from a dialog where he selects the file and adds to the resource.

The problem is for every file of type "A", i need to create  a new Resource and hence and new node in XML.(which my current code isn't able to do)

Initially i came with the following (generalised for brevity)

```
    Project p =new Project("Untitled project"); //Will happen once per project
    Resource res = p.CreateProjectResource("resource1"); 
                  //various params to create resource 
    p.AddResource(res);
    
    //now lets add files to a resource 
    AddFileHelper(res,"C:\myfile1.bin","A",guid.toString()); 
    AddFileHelper(res,"C:\myfile32.bin","B",guid.toString());
    AddFileHelper(res,"C:\myfile56.bin","B",guid.toString());

  
    //The next statement should create a new resource and add the  file to 
    //the new created design
    AddFileHelper(res,"C:\myfile4.bin","A",guid.toString()); // 
    
   //some helper class     :
    //Adds a file of type "type" to a resource "res" with file ID as "id" 
    private AddFileHelper(Resource res,string path,FileType type,string id)
    {
         // path is user defined file path from OpenFile dialog, 
        //type is selected from a Dropdown (of Enum values "A","B",...)
        //id is GUID
        res.AddFile(path,type,id); 
        
       //************ OR it could be also written as  *******
       //ResFile file =new ResFile(path,type,id); 
       //res.AddFile(file);  
                 
       //Update XML file here.. 
    }
```

***The main problem is the User does not create the resources "explicitly" (except for the   first resource) and creation of new Resource depends on the type of the file being   added by the user.***

Also due this design it is difficult to figure out the Resource given a File id.
Only way to track is using the file collection in each Resource class.

Any help??

Thanks All.

This is in reference to a question I asked before [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116941/designhow-to-of-classes-containing-collections-of-other-classes)

Comment: Any question that reads "my code is bad, make it better" is a terrible one, as a rule.  This is the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: I recommend taking out the "refactor-my-code" tag, adding a "design-pattern" tag and renaming the question: "a design for adding resources to a project" or something like that.

Comment: edited now... tag +title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I understand it:

As of now, your `AddFileHelper` only adds files to your project resource labeled `''resource1''` which is a problem because every time a filetype “A” is passed your AddFileHelper, you to make a new resource for your project (`''resource2''`) and add it to that.

There is a very simple way to do this. Within `AddFileHelper` test the `FileType` of the added file and determine whether or not you need a new resource to be added to your project. If the type isn't “A” you'll call the code that you have now and add the file with:

```
res.AddFile(path, type, id);
```

If the type to add is “A” and you need a new resource, just redefine `res` and increment a counter variable of how many resources you have in your project:

```
Resource res = p.CreateProjectResource(resourceName);
resourceCounter++;
```

Where `resourceName` is the string:

```
string resourceName = ''resource'' + resourceCounter;
```

All this should be implemented as your AddFileHelper method.

**Regarding the overall structure of your code, the AddFileHelper should be a project class method.** Here's why:

The `AddFile` method, and the `AddFileHelper` method sound similar but do two very different things. The `AddFile` method belongs to the resource class because it acts on a well defined resource object. However, the `AddFile` method is not enough for your purposes because the resource file to append to is not immediately apparent to the client who has a file and wants to add it to your project. Bbefore the `AddFile` method can be called, the target resource needs to be determined. The job of the `AddFileHelper` method is to determine which resource will call the `AddFile` method. Therefore, the `AddFileHelper` method belongs to the project class and the `AddFile` method to the resource class.

The logical connection between the `AddFileHelper` method and the project class might be more apparent if you renamed the method to `FileResourceAssignment` or something like that.

Comment: where to implement the AddFileHelper..within "Project" class or outside?

Comment: I think AddFileHelper should be a Project class method. The alternative would be to make a FileFactory class (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_design_pattern) and have the Project class implement an AddFile method but that doesn't seem to be necessary in your case.

Comment: I was thinking of the same but thing is File belongs to a Resource more than to a Project. So wouldn't resource.AddFile(file) be more logically correct than Project.AddFileHelper(file) ??
 this is the part which confuses me....